# How to import env variables in child jenkinsfile from parent jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, monorepo

I have a monorepo setup where I am trying to dispatch service Jenkinsfile from root JenkinsFile
The structure looks like this:

```
  Monorepo
  - Jenkinsfile (at root)
  - services
    - Jenkinsfile (services Jenkinsfile)
    - Service A
      - src/
    - Service B
      - src/
```

Service Jenkinsfile is triggered from root Jenkinsfile.

These env variables are working fine in root jenkinsfile but they are giving null values in service jenkinsfile.

```
stage('Echo env') {
      echo "Branch_name=${env.BRANCH_NAME}, PR_Branch_change=${env.CHANGE_BRANCH}, PR_Key=${env.CHANGE_ID}, PR_Base=${env.CHANGE_TARGET}, Key=$CHANGE_ID, branch=$CHANGE_BRANCH, base=$CHANGE_TARGET" 
} // Stage is same in both the jenkinsfile
```

[image: Printing root jenkinsfile env variables]
In service jenkinsfile either gives error: [image: Error] or Print `Null` values [image: null values]
Is there any way to import or reference the env variables from another (root) Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to get env variables values printed from parent jenkinsfile to child jenkinsfile

Here is the post I went through and somehow it helped me getting end result

[Pass environment variables from parent job to child job Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430534/pass-environment-variables-from-parent-job-to-child-job-jenkins-pipeline)